# c++ operator is ambiguous and other

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi I have this c++ project which gets me some weird error which I have no idea how to fix. So if someone can give me a solution, that would be great.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;
    using std::ostream;
    using std::endl;
    using std::cout; 

    class CStudentEmploy
    {
    private:
        string m_strName;
        string m_strFacNum;
        int m_iMinutes;

    public:

        CStudentEmploy(int m = 0) // Podrazbirasht se konstruktor 
        {
            m_strName = "N/A";
            m_strFacNum = "N/A";
            m_iMinutes = m;
        }

        CStudentEmploy(string n, string f, int m) // Ekspliciten konstruktor
        {
            m_strName = n;
            m_strFacNum = f;
            m_iMinutes = m;
        }

        CStudentEmploy(const CStudentEmploy &obj) // Copy konstruktor 
        {
            m_strName = obj.m_strName;
            m_strFacNum = obj.m_strFacNum;
            m_iMinutes = obj.m_iMinutes;
        }

        string GetName()
        {
            return m_strName;
        }

        string GetFacNum()
        {
            return m_strFacNum;
        }

        int GetMinutes()
        {
            return m_iMinutes;
        }

        void SetName (string n)
        {
            m_strName = n;
        }
        void SetFacNum (string f)
        {
            m_strFacNum = f;
        }
        void SetMinutes (int m)
        {
            m_iMinutes = m;
        }

        CStudentEmploy operator =(CStudentEmploy obj)
        {
            m_strName = obj.m_strName;
            m_strFacNum = obj.m_strFacNum;
            m_iMinutes = obj.m_iMinutes;
            return *this;
        }


        bool operator < (const CStudentEmploy& obj) const
        {
            return m_iMinutes < obj.m_iMinutes;
        }

        CStudentEmploy operator +(const CStudentEmploy &obj) const
        {
            return CStudentEmploy(m_iMinutes + obj.m_iMinutes);
        }

        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, CStudentEmploy &obj);
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, CStudentEmploy &obj);

    };


    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CStudentEmploy &obj) {
        os<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(8)<<obj.GetName()
             <<"|"<<setw(11)<<obj.GetFacNum()
             <<"|"<<setw(8)<<obj.GetMinutes()<<endl;
        return os;
    }


    istream& operator>>(istream& is, CStudentEmploy &obj) {
        string tmp_strName;
        string tmp_strFacNum;
        int tmp_iMinutes;
        is >> tmp_strName >> tmp_strFacNum >> tmp_iMinutes;
        obj.SetName(tmp_strName);
        obj.SetFacNum(tmp_strFacNum);
        obj.SetMinutes(tmp_iMinutes);
        return is;
    }



    class CAnalizeTime { 
    private:
        vector<CStudentEmploy>m_vData;

        void add(CStudentEmploy employ) {
            m_vData.push_back(employ);
        }

    public:

        CStudentEmploy getEmployAt(int i)
        {
            return m_vData[i];
        }

        long getEmployCount()
        {
            return m_vData.size();
        }

        CAnalizeTime()
        {
            ifstream fs;
            fs.open("test.txt");
            if(!fs.is_open()) cout<<"error opening file!\n";
            CStudentEmploy employ;
            while(!fs.eof())
            {
                fs>>employ;
                add(employ);
            }
        }

        CAnalizeTime(const string& strFileName)
        {
            ifstream fs;
            fs.open(strFileName.c_str());
            if(!fs.is_open()) cout<<"error opening file!\n";
            CStudentEmploy employ;
            while(!fs.eof())
            {
                fs>>employ;
                add(employ);
            }
        }

        void Sort()
        {
            sort(m_vData.begin(),m_vData.end());
        }

        vector<int> calcNums(int iR1,int iR2,int iR3,
                                 int iR4,int iR5,int iR6)
        {
            vector<int> resultVector;
            for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                resultVector.push_back(0);
            }
            for (i=0;i<m_vData.size();i++)
            {
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR1
                             &&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR2) 
                                    resultVector[0]++;//[iR1-iR2)
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR2
                             &&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR3) 
                                   resultVector[1]++;//[iR2-iR3)
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR3
                              &&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR4) 
                                   resultVector[2]++;//[iR3-iR4)
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR4
                            &&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR5) 
                                  resultVector[3]++;//[iR4-iR5)
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR5
                             &&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR6) 
                                  resultVector[4]++;//[iR5-iR6)
            }
            return resultVector;
        }

        double calcMean() 
        {
            double sum=0;
            for (int i=0;i<m_vData.size();i++)
            {
                sum+=m_vData[i].GetMinutes();
            }
            return sum/m_vData.size();
        }
    };

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CAnalizeTime &obj) 
    {
        for (int i=0;i<obj.getEmployCount();i++)
        {
            cout<<obj.getEmployAt(i);
        }
        return os;
    }

    void main() 
    {
        CAnalizeTime myTimeAnalyzer;
        //myTimeAnalyzer.Sort();
        cout<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(8)
                <<"Name"<<setw(12)
                <<"|FacNum"<<setw(8)<<"|Minutes"<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<myTimeAnalyzer;
        cout<<"CalcMean result:"<<myTimeAnalyzer.calcMean()<<endl;
        vector<int>myCalcNums = myTimeAnalyzer.calcNums(1,50,100,200,400,800);
        cout<<"CalcNums result:"
                <<myCalcNums[0]<<","
                <<myCalcNums[1]<<","
                <<myCalcNums[2]<<","
                <<myCalcNums[3]<<","
                <<myCalcNums[4]<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
```

I'm getting this error when I run it on VC6 `error C2593: 'operator >>' is ambiguous`, and I get this error when I run it on 2010

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test_project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/14/2013 10:02:29 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\test_project.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_project\test_project\Debug\test_project.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.80
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My question is what is causing this errors

I have the errors here on these lines:

```
CAnalizeTime()
        {
            ifstream fs;
            fs.open("test.txt");
            if(!fs.is_open()) cout<<"error opening file!\n";
            CStudentEmploy employ;
            while(!fs.eof())
            {
                fs>>employ;
                add(employ);
            }
        }

        CAnalizeTime(const string& strFileName)
        {
            ifstream fs;
            fs.open(strFileName.c_str());
            if(!fs.is_open()) cout<<"error opening file!\n";
            CStudentEmploy employ;
            while(!fs.eof())
            {
                fs>>employ;
                add(employ);
            }
        }
```

This is what the error message looks like:

```
--------------------Configuration: project_testing - Win32 Debug--------------------
Compiling...
project_testing.cpp
D:\My Documents\project_testing\project_testing\project_testing.cpp(143) : error C2593: 'operator >>' is ambiguous
D:\My Documents\project_testing\project_testing\project_testing.cpp(156) : error C2593: 'operator >>' is ambiguous
Error executing cl.exe.

project_testing.obj - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: You have no valid `main` in your code.

Comment: can you be a little more specific

Comment: `void main` is not valid in C++.  It should be `int main`

Comment: Either your compilation setup is wrong, or your main function is wrongly typed.

Comment: VC6 is old, unsupported, doesn't even support the 1998 C++ standard and therefore it is not suitable for any work or learning unless you have very specific reasons to use it. Delete it, you won't need it and you are better off without it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `obj.getEmployAt(i);` returns a rvalue temporary `CStudentEmploy` object which you send to your `operator<<` overlaod. But the operator overload expects **a reference** and can not bind to an rvalue.

You will have to take a const reference instead

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CStudentEmploy &obj) {
                                 ^^^^^
```

and fix the functions used in it as `const` for example

```
string GetName() const { return m_strName; }
                 ^^^^^
```

---

---

Or you can fix your `getEmployAt` function to return a *reference* instead.

```
CStudentEmploy& getEmployAt(int i) { return m_vData[i]; }
             ^^^
```

---

---

As mentioned in the comments: *I don't know what compiler you are using but `void` is not a valid return value for `main`. use `int main` and `return 0;`*

Comment: it fixed two of the three ambiguous errors, i have this error here as well:

 CAnalizeTime()
     {
      ifstream fs;
      fs.open("test.txt");
      if(!fs.is_open()) cout<<"error opening file!\n";
      CStudentEmploy employ;
      while(!fs.eof())
      {
       fs>>employ;
       add(employ);
      }
     }
     
     CAnalizeTime(const string& strFileName)
     {
      ifstream fs;
      fs.open(strFileName.c_str());
      if(!fs.is_open()) cout<<"error opening file!\n";
      CStudentEmploy employ;
      while(!fs.eof())
      {
       fs>>employ;
       add(employ);
      }
     }

Comment: @user2374907 can you put the errors as an edit to your question. And what is `term`?

Comment: @user2374907 can you put it in your question. It is not wasy to read in the comments.

Comment: Ok i've put them in the question

Comment: @user2374907 I don't see the errors? Can you also put what errors are reported. Preferably the error message from the compiler.

Comment: Here you go:--------------------Configuration: project_testing - Win32 Debug--------------------
Compiling...
project_testing.cpp
D:\My Documents\project_testing\project_testing\project_testing.cpp(143) : error C2593: 'operator >>' is ambiguous
D:\My Documents\project_testing\project_testing\project_testing.cpp(156) : error C2593: 'operator >>' is ambiguous
Error executing cl.exe.

project_testing.obj - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Comment: @user2374907 WHY are you putting it in the comment. Can you please put it in your question. I can't read it here.

Comment: yeah sry i've put them in the question now

Comment: @user2374907 Your code compiles fine with gcc4.8 and VS2008. Is there something you are not showing here? what complier are you using?

Comment: I'm testing this on VS6, on VS2010 I'm getting the error I posted at the beginning

Comment: @user2374907 did you fix your main? `int main`

Comment: @user2374907 I am sorry but there is nothing else I can do. I hope you fixed everything suggested and not just fix one thing. And use one compiler report errors from one complier. I can not figure out errors from two different compilers.

Comment: @user2374907 Just go throught the comments and the answer. make sure everything is fixed. Figure out if there is something else you are not showing here. Because your code works fine with two completely unrelated compilers. The problem is definitely something overlooked and not mentioned here.