# OOP project function error

Tags: c++, oop

I'm doing this project on c++ and I have to return unique elements.  If someone can lend a shoulder and help me with this
Here is a sample of my entire code

```
#include <iostream.h>
class CService {
  private:
  string m_strSeller;
  //other stuff
};

class CServiceAnalizer {
 //other stuff
 unique function
};
```

Here is how my unique function looks like

```
CService unique (const CService& a, const CService& b) {
            if(a.m_strSeller==b.m_strSeller) {
                return b.m_strSeller;
            }

            CService result = a.m_strSeller;
            while (++a.m_strSeller != b.m_strSeller) {
                if (!(*result == *a.m_strSeller)) {
                    *(++result)=*a.m_strSeller;
                }
            }

            return ++result;
        }
```

One of the main errors is `'m_strSeller' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'`

If someone can explain to me what exactly is making the compiler this errors and how can I fix them.

```
These are the errors from the compiler:
--------------------Configuration: Proekt - Win32 Debug--------------------
Compiling...
Proekt.cpp
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(191) : error C2248: 'm_strSeller' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'
        D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'm_strSeller'
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(191) : error C2248: 'm_strSeller' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'
        D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'm_strSeller'
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(192) : error C2248: 'm_strSeller' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'
        D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'm_strSeller'
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(192) : error C2664: '__thiscall CService::CService(int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' to 'int'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(195) : error C2248: 'm_strSeller' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'
        D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'm_strSeller'
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(195) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' to 'class CService'
        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(196) : error C2248: 'm_strSeller' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'
        D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'm_strSeller'
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(196) : error C2675: unary '++' : 'const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the p
redefined operator
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(196) : error C2248: 'm_strSeller' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'
        D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'm_strSeller'
D:\My Documents\OOP Proekt\Proekt\Proekt.cpp(196) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
Error executing cl.exe.

Proekt.obj - 10 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

My Entire code:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;
    using std::ostream;
    using std::endl;
    using std::cout; 

    class CService
    {
    private:
        string m_strClient;
        string m_strSeller;
        int m_iMinutes;

    public:

        CService(int m = 0) // Podrazbirasht se konstruktor 
        {
            m_strClient = "N/A";
            m_strSeller = "N/A";
            m_iMinutes = m;
        }

        CService(string c, string s, int m) // Ekspliciten konstruktor
        {
            m_strClient = c;
            m_strSeller = s;
            m_iMinutes = m;
        }

        CService(const CService &obj) // Copy konstruktor 
        {
            m_strClient = obj.m_strClient;
            m_strSeller = obj.m_strSeller;
            m_iMinutes = obj.m_iMinutes;
        }

        string GetClient() const
        {
            return m_strClient;
        }

        string GetSeller() const
        {
            return m_strSeller;
        }

        int GetMinutes() const
        {
            return m_iMinutes;
        }

        void SetClient (string c)
        {
            m_strClient = c;
        }
        void SetSeller (string s)
        {
            m_strSeller = s;
        }
        void SetMinutes (int m)
        {
            m_iMinutes = m;
        }

        CService operator =(CService obj)
        {
            m_strClient = obj.m_strClient;
            m_strSeller = obj.m_strSeller;
            m_iMinutes = obj.m_iMinutes;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator < (const CService &obj) const
        {
            return m_iMinutes < obj.m_iMinutes;
        }

        CService operator +(const CService &obj) const
        {
            return CService(m_iMinutes + obj.m_iMinutes);
        }

        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, CService &obj);
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, CService &obj);

    };

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CService &obj) {
        os<<obj.GetClient()<<obj.GetSeller()<<obj.GetMinutes()<<endl;
        return os;
    }


    istream& operator>>(istream& is, CService &obj) {
        string tmp_strClient;
        string tmp_strSeller;
        int tmp_iMinutes;
        is>>tmp_strClient>>tmp_strSeller>>tmp_iMinutes;
        obj.SetClient(tmp_strClient);
        obj.SetSeller(tmp_strSeller);
        obj.SetMinutes(tmp_iMinutes);
        return is;
    }



    class CServiceAnalizer { 
    private:
        vector<CService>m_vData;

        void add(CService seller) {
            m_vData.push_back(seller);
        }
        //13.05.2013
    public:
        CService getSellerAt(int i)
        {
            return m_vData[i];
        }

        long getSellerCount()
        {
            return m_vData.size();
        }

        CServiceAnalizer()
        {
            ifstream fs;
            fs.open("test.txt");
            if(!fs.is_open()) cout<<"error opening file!\n";
            CService seller;
            while(!fs.eof())
            {
                fs>>seller;
                add(seller);
            }
        }

        CServiceAnalizer(const string& strFileName)
        {
            ifstream fs;
            fs.open(strFileName.c_str());
            if(!fs.is_open()) cout<<"error opening file!\n";
            CService seller;
            while(!fs.eof())
            {
                fs>>seller;
                add(seller);
            }
        }

        void Sort()
        {
            sort(m_vData.begin(),m_vData.end());
        }

        double calcMean() 
        {
            double sum=0;
            for (int i=0;i<m_vData.size();i++)
            {
                sum+=m_vData[i].GetMinutes();
            }
            return sum/m_vData.size();
        }

        vector<int> calcNums(int iR1,int iR2,int iR3,int iR4,int iR5)
        {
            vector<int> resultVector;
            for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                resultVector.push_back(0);
            }
            for (i=0;i<m_vData.size();i++)
            {
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR1&&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR2) resultVector[0]++;//[iR1-iR2)
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR2&&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR3) resultVector[1]++;//[iR2-iR3)
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR3&&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR4) resultVector[2]++;//[iR3-iR4)
                if(m_vData[i].GetMinutes()>=iR4&&m_vData[i].GetMinutes()<iR5) resultVector[3]++;//[iR4-iR5)
            }
            return resultVector;
        }

        CService unique (const CService& a, const CService& b) {
            if(a.m_strSeller==b.m_strSeller) {
                return b.m_strSeller;
            }

            CService result = a.m_strSeller;
            while (++a.m_strSeller != b.m_strSeller) {
                if (!(*result == *a.m_strSeller)) {
                    *(++result)=*a.m_strSeller;
                }
            }

            return ++result;
        }
    };

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CServiceAnalizer &obj) 
    {
        for (int i=0;i<obj.getSellerCount();i++)
        {
            cout<<obj.getSellerAt(i);
        }
        return os;
    }

    int main() 
    {
        CServiceAnalizer myAnalyzer;
        //myAnalyzer.Sort();
        cout<<"Client"<<"Seller"<<"Minutes"<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<myAnalyzer;
        cout<<"CalcMean result:"<<myAnalyzer.calcMean()<<endl;
        vector<int>myCalcNums = myAnalyzer.calcNums(1,20,50,80,100);
        cout<<"CalcNums result:"<<myCalcNums[0]<<","<<myCalcNums[1]<<","<<myCalcNums[2]<<","<<myCalcNums[3]<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can fix this my making m_strSeller public. You will probably run into another error though when you try to assign a `a.m_strSeller` to `CService result` since they are different type objects.

Comment: can you post the compiler errors? hard to help with out them

Comment: we need more source or this is pointless.

Comment: @UpAndAdam I've added my entire code

Comment: It looks like you're using `*` and `++` in the most peculiar ways, that make very little sense. `string` has neither, and it looks like `CService` doesn't have them either.

Comment: i'm trying to create the function based on this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/

Comment: How many times are you asking the same question on here?
i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550863/c-operator-is-ambiguous-and-other

Comment: @user2374907 Did you expect to be able to copy a function that uses *iterators* and have it magically work with other classes, only because it has the same name?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the data member `m_strSeller` which is private (e.g. you can't access it). You should implement getters/setters or make `CServiceAnalizer::unique()` a friend of `CService`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is with lines like this

```
if(a.m_strSeller==b.m_strSeller) {
```

It's a private field, so only that instance can access it.  If you need to read the field, use a getter

```
public:
string get_m_strSeller()
{
    return this.m_strSeller;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

==UPDATED Based on Editors Updates==

Others have missed other clear type compatibility issues.

CService::m_strSeller is defined in your header as string.  They are not pointers to strings they are strings.  Which means a couple things.

As far as I can tell you have not defined a constructor that takes a string or defined an assignment operator that takes a string as the r-value.

- There is no ++operator for a string.
- You can't do this

> CService result = a.m_strSeller

result is not of the same type as a string, you have an asignment operator only for CService = CService.

- You also can't dereference things that arent pointers.
  Namely *result, *a, *b and *a.m_strSellar or *b.m_strSellar. There are no pointers in your whole code so unless you are multiplying there shouldnt be any *'s
- You haven't told us what function unique is trying to do.
- You can't manipulate constants references.  So unless you defined m_strSeller as mutable, which you didn't and shouldnt, all of your "++" operations are illegal in your unique function.

Comment: The task in my project says, return unique sellers, so I'm trying to do that

Comment: you mean the task in your homework... That doesn't tell me how you are trying to accomplish that. What is unique supposed to return with respect to what its input is?

Comment: also you can't possibly return this result from your unique function because you are returning a single c service, where as if A and B are different you'd need to return both

Answer (score 0):

While a `getter` will work it has the downside of exposing class internals.

Another solution is to add an `unique` method to `CService` (altgough I would give the method another, more expressive, name).

It can be either:

```
static CService CService::unique( const CService& a, const CService& b );
```

or

```
CService CService::unique( const CService& other );
```

I don't really know what the logic inside is supposed to do though. You are using `string` very creatively with that ++.

EDIT.

If you are trying to output the collection of unique `m_strSeller` from the `CService` objects kept in `m_vData` then:

- add a `CService::GetSeller` method
- add a `std::set<std::string> CServiceAnalizer::GetUniqueSellers()` method that iterates through the `m_vData` vector and adds each iterm's seller to a std::set (which guarantees uniqueness)